# Handling dynamic links in Flutter app to go to specific pages within app

Tags: firebase, flutter, deep-linking

I created a dynamic link in Firebase Console and added the code in Flutter to take me to a specific page within my app . This works . I am unsure now thou of how to create more dynamic links within Flutter to take me to more/other pages within my app  after creating a new dynamic link in Firebase Console . I followed code below from a tutorial :

```
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Dynamic Links Example',
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/': (BuildContext context) => MyApp(),
      '/helloworld': (BuildContext context) => LinkPage(),
    },
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _linkMessage;
  bool _isCreatingLink = false;
  String _testString =
      "To test: long press link and then copy and click from a non-browser "
      "app. Make sure this isn't being tested on iOS simulator and iOS xcode "
      "is properly setup. Look at firebase_dynamic_links/README.md for more "
      "details.";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDynamicLinks(); //
  }

  void setupNotification() async {
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print(token);
    });

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("Message: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("Message: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("Message: $message");
      },
    );
  }

  void initDynamicLinks() async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
      final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

      print(deepLink);

      if (deepLink != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/helloworld');
      }
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
    });

    final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;

    if (deepLink != null) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/helloworld');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _createDynamicLink(bool short) async {
    setState(() {
      _isCreatingLink = true;
    });

    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'http://cx4k7.app.goo.gl',
      link: Uri.parse('My http url'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'my package id/name',
        minimumVersion: 0,
      ),
      dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
        shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.short,
      ),
    );

    Uri url;
    if (short) {
      final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await parameters.buildShortLink();
      url = shortLink.shortUrl;
    } else {
      url = await parameters.buildUrl();
    }

    setState(() {
      _linkMessage = url.toString();
      _isCreatingLink = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statements for what happens if deeplink not null was key to finding answer . So was just a matter of writing few if statements for what happens when deeplink has same value as in FCM Console